# Prepopulate email body when subscriber replies to an email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I am trying to customize links within emails where, if the subscriber clicks on the link (like for an email address), it will prepopulate the email body for them - similar to how when you click a link's properties, you can have it auto populate with the subject.

Is there an AMPscript that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can append both `subject` and `body` parameters to your `mailto` links in order to pre-populate content. Here's a simple example:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?subject=Hello%20World&body=Body%20Content">Reply</a>
```